# nginx + PHP-FPM = permission denied error 13

Tags: php, nginx, администрирование

Установил на чистый vps centos 7, nginx 1.6.3 и PHP-FPM 5.6.18
При попытке обратиться к сайту, получаю в логи nginx ошибку

```
2016/03/01 17:39:58 [crit] 1536#0: *13 stat() "/home/site/1.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 178.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: site4.ru, request: "GET /1.php HTTP/1.1", host: "173.xxx.xxx.xxx"
```

В /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf указал:

```
; RPM: apache Choosed to be able to access some dir as httpd
user = apache
; RPM: Keep a group allowed to write in log dir.
group = apache
...
listen = /run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock
...
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0660
```

В файле nginx.conf сайт установлен так:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
........
server {
    listen       173.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;
    server_name site4.ru;

    location / {
        root   /home/site;
        index  index.php;
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
               rewrite ^ /index.php last;
               break;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /home/site;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Перерыл весь инет, ничего не помогает! Вроде права везде совпадают, на другом моём сервере при таких настройках все работает. Помогите советом.

Comment: SELinux включен? Покажите права на `/home/site/`

Comment: Да, почитал про SELinux, проверил - он оказался включён. Отключил, перезагрузился и все заработало. Но теперь мучает вопрос, а насколько безопасно отключать SELinux? На VPS работаю один, других юзеров там нет, все делаю под рутом. Можно отключать SELinux в этом случае?

Comment: На вкус и цвет пряников нет, можно отключить, можно один раз настроить. Если не лень, я бы настроил, лишним не будет. Вот [статья](https://www.opennet.ru/tips/2915_centos_rhel_selinux_apache_httpd.shtml) в тему .